# Ways to collect a physical signature with a web site on iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, web-applications

I'm looking to fill out a form from a web page that will include a box to collect a physical signature, on an iPad or iPhone. Think of a repair visit acknowledgment form, where after the technician does some work they can fill out things on the form on the website, and then hand the iPad to the customer to sign (using a stylus) What kind of technologies are an option there?

A flash control isn't an option because it doesn't run on iOS. Same with a Java applet.

A native iOS app is not an option because the distribution profile (around 350 users) doesn't fit (and anyway, relying on Apple's permission isn't desirable here).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134585/signature-capture-possible-in-various-mobile-web-browsers

Comment: Not voting as dupe because it's not specifically targeting iOS but there is usable input there

Comment: This one (suggested in the other question) looks really nice. http://www.supersignature.com/features.aspx

Comment: Enterprise distribution supposedly allows up to 500 devices...

Comment: @tc, actually (it used to be that) the enterprise had to have 500 employees minimum. I see they relaxed that requirement now, and only require a D&B number, but it would still require their approval. I would be very surprised if they limited an in-house app to 500.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an older question, but I think Sketch.js may be a valid (and Free) solution: https://github.com/intridea/sketch.js

It's not specifically for signatures, but will allow for any sort of drawing by touch (or mouse) inside of a standard web browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to roll your own, I'd use JavaScript which can detect touches on the iPhone, but I don't know whether it is accurate enough for your use case. There a Javascript library called jQTouch and it has touch events http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/wiki/CallbackEvents.

Answer (score 1):

[Super Signature](http://www.supersignature.com/features.aspx) seems to do exactly what I need. Thanks @Pekka!

Comment: It would be great to see an actual live demo instead of their video "demo".

Comment: Did you end up using Super Signature?  If yes, was it fairly easy to integrate and does it work pretty well?  I'm waiting for a trial download from them and was hoping to get your thoughts before I play with it.

Comment: @Don, no I didn't use it yet (the project that would need it didn't start yet).