# HTML control to capture stylus signature

Tags: html, mobile

Is there an html control that I can use on a web page that, when browsed to using a touch device (iPad, Samsung Galaxy Tab), can capture a signature input by the user using a stylus?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Signature capture possible in various mobile web browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134585/signature-capture-possible-in-various-mobile-web-browsers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The highest-voted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134585/signature-capture-possible-in-various-mobile-web-browsers) mentioned this on Nov. 12, 2011:

> There is a jQuery plugin to do this now ->
>   http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad

That link is inactive as of March 17, 2016, but the relevant repository is on GitHub: https://github.com/thomasjbradley/signature-pad

Comment: This link is dead.

Comment: That issue was addressed.

Answer (score 1):

Try jSignature

MIT, Canvas + Flash backup.

http://willowsystems.github.com/jSignature/#/demo/